# ExtJs: Get store data on store creation

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, store

I have an in-line store that is inside of a simple combobox. This store has some default inline-data. Now I'm looking for an event that gets fired once the store is created and this event needs to supply me with the data that is in the store.

I tried it like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose',
    store: {
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: [
            {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
        ],
        data : [
            {"name":"TestName_A"},
            {"name":"TestName_B"},
            {"name":"TestName_C"},
        ],
        listeners: {
            load: function(store) {
                let records = store.getData()
                records.forEach(record => {
                    console.log(record.getField('name'))
                })
            }
        }
    },
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'name',
    displayField: 'name',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

But it doesn't work. `store.getData()` doesn't seem to contain my records.

There's my fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=v7#fiddle/1h53

Comment: Change your code in your load() function to store.getData().items to receive your records.

Comment: It returns an empty array and after a while that empty suddenly contains 3 constructors. Wtf? https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=v7#fiddle/1h74 (When the debugger-breakpoint is hit, the array is empty. Once you resume execution it contains an array of constructors.)

Comment: If you want to iterate the store records, use `store.each`. Also `getField` returns a field configuration, you probably want `get`.

Comment: I get nothing: https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=v7#fiddle/1h79

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this now store show console data:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose',
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'name',
    displayField: 'name',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(me) {

            var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                //autoLoad: true,
                fields: [
                    {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
                ],
                data : [
                    {"name":"TestName_A"},
                    {"name":"TestName_B"},
                    {"name":"TestName_C"},
                ],
                listeners: {
                    datachanged : function(store) {
                        Ext.each(store.data.items,function(rec){
                           console.log(rec.data.name); 
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            me.setStore(store);
            store.load();
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the problem by accessing the store after it's combobox is rendered:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=v7#fiddle/1h7c

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose',
    store: {
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: [
            {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
        ],
        data : [
            {"name":"TestName_A"},
            {"name":"TestName_B"},
            {"name":"TestName_C"},
        ],
    },
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'name',
    displayField: 'name',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(me) {
            let store = me.getStore()
            console.log("Event fired!")
            store.each(record => {
                console.log(record.get('name'))
            })
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by creating store afterrender of combo box and set store to combo box.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose',
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'name',
    displayField: 'name',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(me) {

            var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                autoLoad: true,
                fields: [
                    {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
                ],
                data : [
                    {"name":"TestName_A"},
                    {"name":"TestName_B"},
                    {"name":"TestName_C"},
                ],
                listeners: {
                    load: function(store) {
                        Ext.each(store.data.items,function(rec){
                           console.log(rec.data.name); 
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            me.setStore(store);
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Nothing is ever printed to the console.

Comment: That is because store load is working when you use proxy. In your case, store data is static. That's the reason load function is not called.

Comment: just comment autoLoad:true;
and Add store.load() after me.setStore(store);